# Modifying a string in an array using an array variable that has an array in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to loop through an array of strings using several for loops to call each array item. I'm having some trouble getting just the right code to pull it off. I have tried using global definitions of arrays and so on.

```
var An = new Array(            
       "11111100011111",       
       "11111000011111",      
       "11110011001111", 
       "11100000000111", 
       "11001111110011", 
       "10011111111001");  
var Bn = new Array(            
       "1000000001",       
       "1001111001",      
       "1000000001", 
       "1000000001", 
       "1001111001", 
       "1000000001"); 

// This second part sits in a onload function.
var alphabet = "AB".split("");

for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {       
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     var my_object = {};
     my_object = window[alphabet[x] + 'n[' + i + ']'];
     my_object = window[my_object].replace(/0/g, "B");
     my_object = window[my_object].replace(/1/g, "_");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you making this so complicated?

Comment: I have a lot of arrays to run through.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where do you set `name`? Why does `x` go until `6`, if you use `alphabet[x]`, and `alphabet.length==2`?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here?  I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I am trying to run through a bunch of arrays that each hold 6 sets of strings. I want to modify those strings using .replace . My problem is coming up with a way to name the array item I want to modify within the loop.

Comment: I'm still not understanding.  What significance does `alphabet` have here?  What is `window[my_object]` supposed to accomplish?  Where are you trying to access `An` and `Bn`?

Comment: `window[alphabet[x] + 'n[' + i + ']'];` is wrong and should be `window[alphabet[x]+'n'][i];` if at all. However, you shouldn't use `window` like that, rather define your maps as `var arrays = {A:[…],B:[…]}` and access them normally there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is put `An` and `Bn` into an object.  This will make it *much* easier to reference later on.

```
var alphabet = {
    An: [
       "11111100011111",       
       "11111000011111",      
       "11110011001111", 
       "11100000000111", 
       "11001111110011", 
       "10011111111001"
    ],
    Bn: [
       "1000000001",       
       "1001111001",      
       "1000000001", 
       "1000000001", 
       "1001111001", 
       "1000000001"
    ]
};
```

Then you pick out the array you want and loop over it.

```
var arrays = ['A', 'B'];
for(var x = 0, xLen = arrays.length; x < xLen; x++){
    var my_key = arrays[x]+'n';
    for(var i = 0, iLen = alphabet[my_key].length; i < iLen; i++){
        alphabet[my_key][i] = alphabet[my_key][i].replace(/0/g, "B");
        alphabet[my_key][i] = alphabet[my_key][i].replace(/1/g, "_");
    }
}
```

Actually, for the inner `for` loop, you can also use `Array.map`.

```
var arrays = ['A', 'B'];
for(var x = 0, xLen = arrays.length; x < xLen; x++){
    var my_key = arrays[x]+'n';
    alphabet[my_key] = alphabet[my_key].map(function(val){
        val = val.replace(/0/g, "B");
        val = val.replace(/1/g, "_");
        return val;
    });
}
```